# Atom compilation failure with SASS Watch package

Tags: node.js, sass, atom-editor

I've installed Atom and Node.js, added my node paths to the system variables, rebooted, then I added SASS Watch package to Atom and when I try to compile a SASS file, I get this error.

> SASS Compile Failed Command failed: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /s /c
>   "C:\Users\MYUSER\.atom\packages\sass-watch\node_modules.bin\node-sass
>   "C:\Users\MYUSER\Desktop\project\style.scss"
>   "C:\Users\MYUSER\Desktop\project\style.css"" 'node' is not
>   recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or
>   batch file.

I've read up on it and it's supposed to be a problem with my Path. But I've tried everything and I still couldn't fix it. Can you help me with this? I would like to replace Netbeans with Atom, but Netbeans is the only one that works for now.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have it on the path? What does echo %PATH% returns if you run in in the command line?

Comment: I ran @echo %PATH%
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program files\Common Files (x86)\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\node\;C:\Ruby21\bin;C:\users\MYUSER\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\node

Comment: I should remove the multiple instances. It's weird, beacause if I check this in my System Variables, not all of these are there. Can you help me how I can fix this?

Comment: The strange thing is that nodejs works from my command line... But not from inside atom?

Comment: Do you still have a problem even after cleaning the PATH?

Comment: Yes. I've restarted, checked my PATH. It's only the correct path to node and it's there only once. The compiler still says the same error.

Comment: try installing node-sass globally: npm install -g node-sass - it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

It's quite an old post, but I've just had the same issue and stumbled upon it.

I solved it simply by installing node-sass globally:

```
npm install -g node-sass
```